# Highlighting in vim

Tags: vim

I'm writing my own vim theme and use this function to speed things up

```
fun <sid>hi(group, guifg, guibg, ctermfg, ctermbg, attr)
  if a:guifg != ""
    exec "hi " . a:group . " guifg=#" . s:gui(a:guifg)
  endif
  if a:guibg != ""
    exec "hi " . a:group . " guibg=#" . s:gui(a:guibg)
  endif
endfun
```

And call it with

```
call <sid>hi("htmlTag", s:gui05, "")
```

But I'm curious on how the empty "" are treated.

Since it skips the entry if it's a "", would the output of the function end up being

```
hi htmlTag guifg=#FFFFFF guibg=NONE
```

where the empty string is evaluated by vim as NONE

or

```
hi htmlTag guifg=#FFFFFF
```

Just skipped all together?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't see how using that function will "speed things up", especially for your users.

Anyway, `call <sid>hi("htmlTag", s:gui05, "")` will likely cause an error because of all the missing parameters.

This command, which uses the right number of parameters, `call <sid>hi("htmlTag", s:gui05, "", "", "", "")` would *obviously* give you this output:

```
hi htmlTag guifg=#FFFFFF
```

There's no reason whatsoever to expect your function to do anything that's not in the function itself.

Comment: The missing parameters are a copy paste error. But thanks.